# Get with Foreign Keys not Returning data properly

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to select all rows from the contact table and return them in a WepApi method but the data is not coming back properly. I can see all the rows in the collection but they don't deserialize properly. I can see why but I don't know how to correct it.

Here is the table structure.

[image]

Here is the results of `var contacts = db.Contacts.AsEnumerable();`

[image]

but the json deserializes incorrectly causing the second contact to be null. 
[image]

The second contact is nested inside the first contacts contact type. This is where the problem lies but I don't know why it's happening or how to correct it.

[image]

I'm using JsonNetSerialization to do the conversions

EDIT Posting Json Code Sections:

```
public class JsonNetSerialization : ISerialization
{
    public string Serialize<T>(object o)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((T)o);
    }

    public object DeSerialize<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());
    }
}


public class BaseRepository
{
    protected ISerialization _serializer;
    protected object deSerialize<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        var retval = _serializer.DeSerialize<T>(stream);
        return retval;
    }

    protected string serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        var retval = _serializer.Serialize<T>(value);
        return retval;
    }
}

public StructureMapRegistry()
{
    For<ISerialization>().Use<JsonNetSerialization>();
}
```

EF Generated Contact Entity:

```
namespace ExtranetDb
{
    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="ExtraNetModel", Name="Contact")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class Contact : EntityObject
    {
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.Int32 ContactID
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.Int32 ContactTypeID
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String FirstName
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String LastName
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String MiddleName
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String NameSuffix
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Address1
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Address2
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String City
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String StateAbbrv
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String PostalCode
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String HomePhoneNumber
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String WorkPhoneNumber
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String MobilePhoneNumber
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String FaxPhoneNumber
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String OtherPhoneNumber
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String PostalCodeSuffix
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> BirthDate
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Email
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.Int16> SuppressLetters
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.Int32> LanguageID
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.DateTime DateCreated
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.DateTime DateUpdated
        { }

        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.Int32> PID
        { }

        [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("ExtraNetModel", "FK_Contact_ContactType", "ContactType")]
        public ContactType ContactType
        { }

        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public EntityReference<ContactType> ContactTypeReference
        { }

        [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("ExtraNetModel", "FK_Contact_SpokenLanguage", "SpokenLanguage")]
        public SpokenLanguage SpokenLanguage
        { }

        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public EntityReference<SpokenLanguage> SpokenLanguageReference
        { }
    }
}
```

Client Side Contact Entity:

```
namespace ProspectingPlatformWeb.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public int ContactID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Contact Type")]
        public Int32 ContactTypeID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a First Name")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Limit 50 Characters")]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Last Name")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Limit 50 Characters")]
        public String LastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
        public String MiddleName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name Suffix")]
        public String NameSuffix { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Address")]
        [MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Limit 60 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("Address 1")]
        public String Address1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Address 2")]
        public String Address2 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a City")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Limit 50 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("City")]
        public String City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a State")]
        [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Limit 2 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("State")]
        public String StateAbbrv { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Postal Code")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Limit 10 Numbers")]
        [DisplayName("Postal Code")]
        public String PostalCode { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Limit 15 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("Home Phone")]
        public String HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Limit 15 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("Work Phone")]
        public String WorkPhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Limit 15 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("Mobile Phone")]
        public String MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Limit 15 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("Fax Number")]
        public String FaxPhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Limit 15 Characters")]
        [DisplayName("Other Phone")]
        public String OtherPhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Limit 4 Numbers")]
        [DisplayName("Postal Code Suffix")]
        public String PostalCodeSuffix { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Birth Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Suppress Letters")]
        public short? SuppressLetters { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Language")]
        public int? LanguageID { get; set; }

        private DateTime dateCreated;

        private DateTime dateUpdated;

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
        public int? PID { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SpokenLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LoanOfficer> LoanOfficers { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public DateTime DateCreated
        {
            get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateCreated.ToString()) ? DateTime.Now : dateCreated; }
            set { dateCreated = value; }
        }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public DateTime DateUpdated
        {
            get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateUpdated.ToString()) ? DateTime.Now : dateUpdated; }
            set { dateUpdated = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510333/serializing-to-json-nullable-date-gets-ommitted-using-json-net-and-web-api-desp

Comment: I updated the post with my implementation of the serializer for inspection. The image with the json data where the second contact is nested is from Postman so I don't think it's the webapi that is doing something somewhere else to the json data. The json is just not being deserialized correctly. All other retrieval works as expected but this is the only entity with FK's

Comment: Can you view the data straight from your browser tools or fiddler?

Comment: What happens if you return a string and try JSON.parse.

Comment: I just checked fiddler and I don't see any json data

Comment: The second contact is still nested in the ContactType of the first contact.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2576-testing-which-ascii-characters-break-json-javascript-object-notation-parsing.htm

Comment: I removed the FK's on the Contact table and updated my EF model, that cleared the problem. For this controlled implementation of these tables I don't need to have them so this will fix the problem.

Comment: Could you post the client and server side contact class definitions. Just namespace, class and attributes... no properties.

Comment: .@codeworx, I updated the question with the EF generated Contact entity and the Client Contact entity classes